# Cross-Origin Request Blocked in mozila firefox? But it is working in chrome browser

Tags: node.js, firefox, kotlin, cors, angular5

I am working on angular 5 application. my site is working in chrome browser well. when i try to log in mozila firefox. i am getting the following CORS exception. please help me with it.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://00.000.000.00/login (this is server url). (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-headers’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).

code:

```
const header = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept':'application/json'
 }),
      'responseType': 'text' as 'text',
 }
```

**it is working chrome browser. but it is not working in firefox browser. can you tell me the reason?**

Comment: You can't set CORS headers to give yourself permission to access another server in the code you use to make the request! That would be stupid! The server you are requesting permission from has to grant you permission.

Comment: const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }),
      'responseType': 'text' as 'text',
    };
    return options;

Comment: @Quentin this  is my header. can you help me with it?

Comment: hi i have a doubt. it is working in chrome but why it is not working in mozila firefox. can you tell me please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `*`, use the exact headers you want. Example:

`Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization`

If you're working with Express, or a derivative, here's an example configuration for a middleware return value:

```
return (req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'your-domain');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

  next();
};
```

Comment: i could not get. could you apply with my code please?

Comment: i added content type

Comment: You can't add these headers on the Angular side of your application. What are you using on the server-side?

Comment: i do not know about backend i am front end developer.

Comment: what should i add in backend side ? can you tell me please? i will inform it to my backend team member.

Comment: They will need to add the headers to their CORS configuration that are expected. I added a sample middleware response for Express.

Comment: ok. thanks man for this

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: hi i have a doubt. it is working in chrome but why it is not working in mozila firefox. can you tell me please?

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal your chrome may be working in insure mode. You can change the settings after which chrome will through same error.

Comment: @mehta rohan how to change settings in chrome?